# SQL join query not working while doing SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2014

I have two tables in SQL named `tblFolding` and `tblStockManagement`. In `tblFolding` I have columns `FoldingID` and `Price`. In `tblStockManagement` I have `FoldingID`(foreign key from `tblFolding`) and `Quantity`.

All I want is calculate the `Total Price` of Items Quantity available in `tblStockManagement` but `Price` comes from `tblFolding` Table. I am trying this but I don't know the exact query. please help me in this.

Comment: SQL-server, mysql or other? What is your excepted output? FoldingID with TotalPrice(Price * Quantity)?

Comment: SQL-Server 2014. actually i dont have output yet because i am confuse with the query. tell me which query will be applied please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will provide total price by folding id wise

```
SELECT TF.FoldingID, SUM(TF.Price * SM.Quantity) AS TotalPrice
FROM tblFolding TF
INNER JOIN tblStockManagement SM ON SM.FoldingID = TF.FoldingID
GROUP BY TF.FoldingID
```

If don't want to get the result by foldingid wise and expect the whole total price, try this:

```
SELECT SUM(TF.Price * SM.Quantity) AS TotalPrice
FROM tblFolding TF
INNER JOIN tblStockManagement SM ON SM.FoldingID = TF.FoldingID
```

---

**UPDATE:**

From your comments, what I understand is you want results according to `FoldingID` in `tblStockManagement` table. So add the WHERE clause and filter by the condition.

```
SELECT TF.FoldingID, SUM(TF.Price * SM.Quantity) AS TotalPrice
FROM tblFolding TF
INNER JOIN tblStockManagement SM ON SM.FoldingID = TF.FoldingID
WHERE SM.FoldingID IN (1, 2, 3, 4) -- modify the condition as per your requirement
GROUP BY TF.FoldingID
```

Comment: looks like you beat me to the answer..i will delete mine...

Comment: @cableload: Oh, hmmm. thanks

Comment: @Arulkumar i want to get result by FoldingID in tblStockManageme table. how i can do this in above query?

Comment: @IqraQureshi The first query is not return the above said result?

Comment: actually its providing me null result, i dont know why is this

Comment: @IqraQureshi If your values having `NULL` values, handle `SELECT SUM(ISNULL(TF.Price, 0) * ISNULL(SM.Quantity, 0)) AS TotalPrice`

Comment: actually i want results according to FoldingID in tblStockManagement table. where to put WHERE clause in first query?

Comment: @IqraQureshi Before the GROUP BY you can add WHERE clause

Answer (score 3):

It may help..

```
SELECT sum (b.Quantity*a.Price) as total price 
FROM tblFolding a, tblStockManagement b 
WHERE a.FoldingID = b.FoldingID
```